# Update a row but before updating, input box should met a record

Tags: php, mysql

The following always echoes `'success'` even if `mname` is not found. If it's not found, it should show `'failed'`. Why is it showing `'success'` when I enter an `mname` that isn't found?

```
<?php 
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","lpdb"); 

//update 
if (isset($_POST['forgot'])){ 
    $password = 'password'; 
    $mname = $_POST['mname']; 
    $query = "UPDATE logindb SET password ='$mname' WHERE mname = '$mname'"; 
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query); 
    if ($result) { 
        echo 'success'; 
    } else { 
        echo 'failed'; 
    } 
}
?>
```

Comment: <?php

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","lpdb");
  
  //update
  if (isset($_POST['forgot'])){
    $password = 'password';
    $mname = $_POST['mname'];
    $query = "UPDATE logindb SET password ='$mname' WHERE mname = '$mname'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    if ($result) {
        echo 'success';
      }
    else {
        echo 'failed';
    }
  }
?>

Comment: THIS IS MY CODE PLEASE HELP ME

Comment: Start with reading [mcve]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) DON'T USE ALL CAPS. All caps is hard to read and comes across as shouting. **Don't** post pictures of code. ([Why](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)) **Do** include the code (as text) *in the question*. Include the inputs, expected output, and actual output. Explain your attempts to determine what the problem is.

Comment: It will echo success.... just because a SQL UPDATE doesn't update any rows, doesn't mean that the query has failed, just that there was no data that matched the criteria.... [mysqli_affected_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php) will tell you how many rows were updated by the query

Comment: first check if mname is found, if not die(with error) else echo success

Answer (score 0):

From [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php):

> Returns `FALSE` on failure. For successful `SELECT`, `SHOW`, `DESCRIBE` or `EXPLAIN` queries `mysqli_query()` will return a `mysqli_result` object. For other successful queries `mysqli_query()` will return `TRUE`.

An update that doesn't update anything isn't a failure, so the result is `TRUE`. Use [`mysqli_affected_rows`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php) to find out how many rows were updated by the `UPDATE`:

```
<?php 
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","lpdb"); 

//update 
if (isset($_POST['forgot'])){ 
    $password = 'password'; 
    $mname = $_POST['mname']; 
    $query = "UPDATE logindb SET password ='$mname' WHERE mname = '$mname'"; 
    mysqli_query($conn, $query);           // ***
    $result = mysqli_affected_rows($conn); // ***
    if ($result > 0) {                     // *** Or perhaps == 1, up to you
        echo 'success'; 
    } else { 
        echo 'failed'; 
    } 
}
?>
```

Comment: why not checking if the user exists first before doing anything else?

Comment: @xYuri: The question isn't "how do I make my logic different," it's "why doesn't this code work"? But separately: There's no point in checking first. If you want to do the update, do the update, and then find out if it updated anything. Two DB ops instead of one isn't a good idea. It's pointless overhead and complication.

Answer (score 0):

firstcheck for `mname`:

`<?php`

```
//check if user submitted first
if (isset($_POST['forgot'])){ 
$password = 'password'; 
$mname = $_POST['mname']; 

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","lpdb"); 
//update 
$query = "UPDATE logindb SET password ='$mname' WHERE mname = '$mname'"; 
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query); 
if($result){
    echo 'success'; 
} else { 
    echo 'failed to update for some reason';
//or maybe echo the db err
echo mysqli_error(); 
} 
?
```

Comment: i love thus ppl who downvote an answer even if they lazy or not kind enough to help the OP :)